# How to give an empty function input with Jest Globals?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

I have a function to be tested, it returns null when the input is empty:

```
const testFunc = (param) => {
  if (param) {
    //blabla
  }
  return null;
};
```

I'd like to test the `return null` when `param` is empty. It is okay with `describe...it...`:

```
describe('check validity', () => {
  it('should return null when input is empty', () => {
    expect(testFunc()).toBe(null);
  });
});
```

However, what should I use in a Globals argument to be an empty `param`?

```
describe('check validity', () => {
  test.each`
  func | parameter | expected
  ${testFunc} | ${**how to be empty here???**} | ${null}
`('returns expected', ({}) => {
    expect(func(parameter)).toBe(expected);
  });
});
```

I tried space, empty object, removing `${}`, none worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pass the zero value of each primitive data type.

E.g.

`index.ts`:

```
export const testFunc = (param) => {
  if (param) {
    return 'teresa teng';
  }
  return null;
};
```

`index.test.ts`:

```
import { testFunc } from './';

describe('check validity', () => {
  test.each`
    func        | parameter    | expected
    ${testFunc} | ${''}        | ${null}
    ${testFunc} | ${undefined} | ${null}
    ${testFunc} | ${null}      | ${null}
    ${testFunc} | ${0}         | ${null}
  `('returns expected', ({ func, parameter, expected }) => {
    expect(func(parameter)).toBe(expected);
  });
});
```

test result:

```
 PASS  examples/67282360/index.test.ts (7.69 s)
  check validity
    ✓ returns null when parameter is  (2 ms)
    ✓ returns null when parameter is undefined (1 ms)
    ✓ returns null when parameter is null
    ✓ returns null when parameter is 0

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       4 passed, 4 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        8.221 s
```